# When can we put furniture in a new build house?

Tags: heating, new-home, joinery

After the heat goes on, when can we put kitchen and furniture in.

We've been told so many different timeframes and it's hard to find any info via a Google search.

Our kitchen guy said heat needs to be on 8 weeks minimum but our contractor says 3-4 weeks? Anyone able to advise us as we don't want to risk ruining our stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Say what? I have no idea what you're asking. Nearly everyone moves in the day the house is done.

Comment: I also have never heard anything like this. Once the paint is dry and you have the keys move in.

Comment: Sorry, im using my phone and accidentally deleted part of the question. We have a kitchen and furniture on order and they say heat needs to be on but mixed advice is confusing us

Comment: Well, sure. Wood furniture shouldn't be subjected to temperature and humidity extremes. Other than that, go nuts.

Comment: I've installed a humidity sensor, I'm assuming if we can get this averaging at least 50% humidity at 21° celcius we should be safe enough? This is all because our rental contract is up at the end of this month so we need to move in as soon as possible.

Comment: "Kitchen guy"  Are you talking about installing countertops or something?

Comment: Over 50% is rarely correct unless the climate is very warm where you are, and new homes are typically very humid to begin with due to evaporation from paint, drywall mud, lumber, etc. The appropriate humidity level depends on the outdoor temperature. There is no standard number. See https://www.hvac.com/faq/recommended-humidity-level-home/

Comment: The kitchen guy is installing a solid wood kitchen and has warned about moisture ingress. @isherwood, is there any way of telling if the walls, floor or air is too damp?

Comment: ok, well flooring , cabinetry, etc is a different matter than furniture. May want to revise the title.  Ultimately you don't want to force a contractor against his determination or they will come back and blame you for any problems.

Comment: you can camp in the new house w/o a furnished kitchen, if you're in a lease crunch